# How to group values ​by month and sum previous values?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I would like to sum the values ​​of a table grouped by months but adding up the previous months.


Example:

[image: Example]

Result that I want:

[image: Result]


The closest I've come so far is:

```
=Query(B2:C4;"select sum(C), B group by B"; -1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY({B2:C}; "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
                where Col1 !='' 
                group by Col1 
                label sum(Col2)''"; 0)
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Month"\ "Total"; {
 QUERY(QUERY({B2:C}; "select toDate(Col1),sum(Col2) 
                      where toDate(Col1) is not null 
                      group by toDate(Col1) 
                      label sum(Col2)'',toDate(Col1)''"; 0); "select Col1"; 0)\ 
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 QUERY(QUERY({B2:C}; "select toDate(Col1),sum(Col2) 
                      where toDate(Col1) is not null 
                      group by toDate(Col1) 
                      label sum(Col2)'',toDate(Col1)''"; 0); "select Col2"; 0))))<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 QUERY(QUERY({B2:C}; "select toDate(Col1),sum(Col2) 
                      where toDate(Col1) is not null 
                      group by toDate(Col1) 
                      label sum(Col2)'',toDate(Col1)''"; 0); "select Col2"; 0))))))*
 QUERY(QUERY({B2:C}; "select toDate(Col1),sum(Col2) 
                      where toDate(Col1) is not null 
                      group by toDate(Col1) 
                      label sum(Col2)'',toDate(Col1)''"; 0); "select Col2"; 0)); SIGN(
 QUERY(QUERY({B2:C}; "select toDate(Col1),sum(Col2) 
                      where toDate(Col1) is not null 
                      group by toDate(Col1) 
                      label sum(Col2)'',toDate(Col1)''"; 0); "select Col2"; 0)))}})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: First of all I appreciate the answer, but that's not what I'm looking for. Note that the value is cumulative. For instance, in 2018/October the correct value is $5629.29 ($2000 from 2018/April).

Comment: are values in B column a valid dates?

Comment: Yes! It could be another format, in general, it does not matter what format it is, but it's valid dates.

Comment: @Scare answer updated